# Mentioning a channel with message.mentions.channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I simply need a little help on how to do a thing on discord.js.

I'm really confused on how to use `message.mentions.channels` and the Documentation isn't helping.

I just need a command that `console.log`'s the channel mentions (like `#annoucements`) Confused as to how. My code right now is

```
if (args.join(" ").mentions.channels = true) {
    console.log(args.join(" ").mentions.channels)
```

This was the command used `-!setWelcome #announcements`.
`args` takes off the prefix/command and leaves the `#announcements`

but it returns `Cannot set property 'channels' of undefined.`

How does one simply? I'm quite confused.

How can I make it so that using `-!setWelcome #announcements` logs `#announcements`?

(I'm still learning, excuse the lack of skill with javascript here)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your if-statement needs 2 or 3 `=` characters to check if `args.join(" ").mentions.channel` is equal to true. Something like this:

```
if (args.join(" ").mentions.channels === true) {
    // ... the rest of your code
```

Second, there are a few ways you can console log all of the channel mentions in a message. Here are two ways you can do it:

Method 1: Log the `Collection` that holds all of the channels. This is useful, but may be overwhelming in the `console` because a `Collection` holds lots of properties and functions inside it.

```
function logMentionChannels(message) {
    let channels = message.mentions.channels;

    console.log(channels);
}
```

Method 2: use `...channels.map()` to pull out only desired channel properties into an Object.

```
function logMentionChannels(message) {
    let myChannels = channels.map(channel => new Object({
        'id': channel.id,
        'name': channel.name
    }));

    console.log(myChannels);
}
```

If you need other ways of looping through channel mentions, see the documentation on the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection)

Answer (score 0):

### v12 Mentions

This may help you!
try this:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
  console.log(`#${channel.name}`);
});
```